# How to sum a row in google sheets without taking the Nth column (N depending on the row number)?

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I'm currently trying to sum some numbers in a single row, but they can't sum a number where the `column number + N` equals the `row number`.

This is my current sheet (it is not completed yet):

[Current sheet](http://prntscr.com/meckst)

The darker column needs to sum the row to its right but ignoring the values where `row not equals column + 1`.

The best I could come up with was the following: `=SUMIF(C2:AA2, NE(ROW(), COLUMN()+1))`, for row `2` (the other rows have a regular sum). But I've noticed that `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` only apply to the current cell (in this case `B2`, thus the resulting `0`). So how do I ignore the values from a range of cells where `NE(ROW(), COLUMN()+1)` for each of them?

For the cell `B2` the result should be `3.15`, in this case, ignoring the cell `C2` because `ROW() == COLUMN()+1`.

Comment: Sure: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jd-jCZuffHuSH0UJSFpybINhynSKv4FboXBSE2DCN7k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either in a different sheet or insert an extra Column to the right of AA and in Row2 there, copied down to suit:

```
=sum(B2:AA2)-offset(B2,,row()-2)
```

The row number is driving the column offset for the cell to "unsum".